# prevent sql server 2005 from printing on console

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I disable the verbose output that gets printed on the console every time I run large queries in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio...

It keeps saying..

```
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
```

and keeps doing that.

I have some print statement in between the SQL, they all get lost! How can I turn this thing off ?

Answer (score 3):

Use this statement on start of batch:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

There is [Documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259204%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You need to write one statement prior your T-SQL.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```